# Visual Studio 2012 use debug libraries instead of release during build

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild

I have a big solution with 100 projects in it (mostly class libraries). I found a strange behavior during building a release version. 
After building a release version I got debug version of some my libraries in bin/Release folder. For many libraries I got correctly release version, but for some I got only debug (DateTime differ and debug code present into Reflector). 
I checked all project properties, there are no problems and no differences between projects. 
What I need to do to change this behavior of Visual Studio?

**Update:**
For example, lets my solution consists of three projects:

- Project1
- Project2 (reference Project1)
- Project3 (reference Project2)

If I build this in release mode I get in Project3\bin\Release directory next builds:

- Project1 (Debug)
- Project2 (Release)
- Project3 (Release)

But! In Project1\bin\Release there is a RELEASE build.

So I assume, that if Project3 don't reference Project1 directly, than MSBuild use debug version of Project1 for build. Can you suggest any solution except reference all not referenced directly libraries?

Answer (score 1):

Check the Configuration screen to see whether you solution "release" configuration is configured to build some "debug" configurations for a number of projects.

As you can see in this screenshot, they don't have to be configured the same for both levels.

[image: Solution and project configuration mismatch]
See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/kkz9kefa.aspx

I suspect you've already checked all these properties, but might have missed some options?

[image: All debug related properties]

If all else fails, have you tried to do a Clean build or a build from the commandline to verify that at least that works?

Comment: Configuration manager is ok too :-( Same configuration "Release" for all project and for solution configuration. Build checkbox checked for all, and platform same for all too.